# How to run the next file only when the previous file ends when running the list in order using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

There are list that I want to execute sequentially using subprocess. What method should I use when I want to execute the next file only after the previous file has been executed?

```
for index in acnt_df.index:
            os.environ["a"] = str(acnt_df["acnt"][index])
            subprocess.Popen(
                ["python", "start.py"]
            )
```

I tried this but it opens the next file before the end of the first one

Comment: subprocess.Popen will execute its task (python in this case) asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen`.

```py
for index in acnt_df.index:
    os.environ["a"] = str(acnt_df["acnt"][index])
    p = subprocess.run(["python", "start.py"])
```

Checkout documentation on `subprocess` module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

There are very fine-grained methods on how to control another running process. If you would like to use full power of `Popen` object, you would go with something like

```py
for index in acnt_df.index:
    os.environ["a"] = str(acnt_df["acnt"][index])
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "start.py"])
    p.wait()
```

However, as you are calling a python script, it is advisable to change it to be able to import it as a module and pass your `a` environmental variable as a normal function argument. I.e. to change `start.py` to be able to do:

```py
import start

for index in acnt_df.index:
    a = str(acnt_df["acnt"][index])
    start.main(a)
```